# Change in X Predicts Change in Y

Tags: modeling, panel-data, prediction, growth-model

I have a fairly small sample (about 50 individuals) measured at three points in time. At each time point, I measure an outcome (Y) and a possible influence on that outcome (X) along with some covariates. But let's ignore the covariates.

I want to see if the change in X from baseline to t2 and t3 is associated with the change in the outcome from baseline to t2 and t3.

How the heck does one model this sort of setup? It's extremely commonly encountered in the areas I work in but we always end up using a random-intercept generalized linear (or sometimes logit) mixed model. To my way of thinking, the association between time-varying X and the time-varying outcome Y is as much about how those things relate at each point in time, rather than how changes in X (specifically) relate to changes in Y.

The time effect in that model (seems to me) to be entirely about changes in Y, adjusting for levels of X at each time point.

The only more on-point method I know of is to estimate latent growth curves for X and Y and evaluate the relationship between the growth-curve parameter. But that is not really advisable with 50 subjects, especially not if we also are going to try and adjust for a handful of covariates.

The whole situation gets even worse when some of the "covariates" are meant to be evaluated for potential mediating effects on the X>-Y association.

Comment: Banerjee, A., Dolado, J. J., Galbraith, J. W., & Hendry, D. F. (1993). *Co-integration, error correction, and the econometric analysis of non-stationary data*. Oxford University Press, USA.